# INI Key as multiple paths error in Configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini, configparser

I have INI file with Server path and Local Paths,i need only keys as list not values.

Server paths, works fine...
in Local paths all 6 are same 'C but not the full path as I mentioned in the key field of ini file

Note:
I need Key alone as List from both sections...

My File:

```
[Server]
//rotork.co.uk\files\ES-LEZO\TESTRIG-DATA\Data\EF1\Database\Test-results.mdb = SS Database 1
//rotork.co.uk\files\CN-SHANGHAI\TESTRIG-DATA\Data\CF1\Database\Test-results.mdb = RAS Database 1
//rotork.co.uk\files\CN-SHANGHAI\TESTRIG-DATA\Data\CF2\Database\Test-results.mdb = RAS Database 2
//rotork.co.uk\files\CN-SHANGHAI\TESTRIG-DATA\Data\CF3\Database\test-results.mdb = RAS Database 3
//rotork.co.uk\files\CN-SHANGHAI\TESTRIG-DATA\Data\CF4\Database\Test-results.mdb = RAS Database 4
//rotork.co.uk\files\CN-SHANGHAI\TESTRIG-DATA\Data\CF5\Database\Test-results.mdb = RAS Database 5
[Local]
C://SVN//CKMotorData//Data//Test-results_EF1.mdb = SS Database 1
C://SVN//CKMotorData//Data//Test-results_CF1.mdb = RAS Database 1
C://SVN//CKMotorData//Data//Test-results_CF2.mdb = RAS Database 2
C://SVN//CKMotorData//Data//Test-results_CF3.mdb = RAS Database 3
C://SVN//CKMotorData//Data//Test-results_CF4.mdb = RAS Database 4
C://SVN//CKMotorData//Data//Test-results_CF5.mdb = RAS Database 5
```

I need all the Local Section key as list.

Server section works by this code

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(Configurations.ini")
MDBList = []
for key in dict(config.items('Server'): #get all keys in a section
    MDBList.append(key)
```

Local Throws error

```
[line 16]: option '"c' in section 'MDBLocal' already exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the caused by the `:` in the filename, 
because the configparser has it's default delimiters set as `delimiters=("=", ":")` 
- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects for more.

Explictly setting the delimiters should work for you.

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser(delimiters=('=',))
config.read_string(ini)

for key in dict(config.items('Local')):
    print(key)
    
# c://svn//ckmotordata//data//test-results_ef1.mdb
# c://svn//ckmotordata//data//test-results_cf1.mdb
# c://svn//ckmotordata//data//test-results_cf2.mdb
# c://svn//ckmotordata//data//test-results_cf3.mdb
# c://svn//ckmotordata//data//test-results_cf4.mdb
# c://svn//ckmotordata//data//test-results_cf5.mdb
```

Comment: Works Good Thanks,  Can we extract the #mentioned stings also?